# Vlookup with two tables

Tags: excel, vlookup

I haven't been able to get this to work after researching other answers. I have the common data in column B in table 1 and column C in table 2. I want to bring the values from the 41st column in table 2 into table 1. The two Vlookup formulas that I have tried pasting in table 1 are below. When I use exact match it returns N/A. When I use approx. match it returns the column header from column 41.

Attempt 1:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, Table2[#All],41,0)
```

Attempt 2:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, CensusData!$A$2:$BM$280, 41, 0)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlookup will look at the first column in in the range for the match.  so with your second attempt the formula should be

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, CensusData!$C$2:$BM$280, 39, 0)
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you!